# Ruby on Rails - how to belong to many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called `Report`, and another called `Phases`. Let's say I have 10 `phases` and I want to have checkboxes on the report form that lists out all the `phases`. How can I collect the items that are checked and store that data in the database?

Do I need to have columns such as `phase_one:integer` `phase_two:integer` `phase_three:integer` and just pull back the ones that aren't null? Or can I somehow store the IDs of x phases in one column and pull back those IDs in an array?

Answer (score 2):

To clarify `NateSHolland`'s answer, you *can* use [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) if the `phases` are predefined:

```
#app/models/report.rb
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :phases
end

#app/models/phase.rb
class Phase < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :reports
end
```

This will allow you to populate the `phase_ids` ([`collection_singular_ids`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many)) attribute from your form:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :reports

#app/controllers/reports_controller.rb
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @report = Report.new
      @phases = Phase.all
   end

   def create
      @report = Report.new report_params
      @report.save
   end

   private

   def report_params
      params.require(:report).permit(:phase_ids)
   end
end

#app/views/reports/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @report do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_check_boxes :phase_ids, @phases, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This would allow you to specify which phases your report has, although it will not have any changes.

---

What I think you'd be better doing is using [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), allowing you to define which `phase` you're referencing:

```
#app/models/report.rb
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :progress
   has_many :phases, through: :progress

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :progress #-> define level
end

#app/models/progress.rb
class Progress < ActiveRecord::Base
   #id report_id phase_id phase_lvl created_at updated_at
   belongs_to :report
   belongs_to :phase
end

#app/models/phase.rb
class Phase < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :progress
   has_many :reports, through: :progress
end
```

The important factor here is the `phase_lvl` column - it's my understanding that you have certain "levels" which your phases will be a part of. I can't describe it properly, but to give you context, you'll have something like...

> - Report is written (phase 5)
> - Report is published (phase 3)
> - Report is Sent (phase 15)

The above will give you the ability to define which "level" each phase denotes. I think this is the distinction you're looking for.

This would be a little more tricky to implement, but worth it:

```
#app/controllers/reports_controller.rb
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @report = Report.new
      @phases = Phase.all
      10.times do 
         @report.progress.build
      end
   end

   def create
      @report = Report.new report_params
      @report.save
   end

   private

   def report_params
      params.require(:report).permit(progress_attributes: [:phase_id, :phase_lvl])
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to define the following:

```
#app/views/reports/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @report do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :progress do |p| %>
      <%= p.collection_select :phase_id, @phases, :id, :name %>
      <%= p.number_field :phase_lvl %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I really appreciate it. So my report won't necessarily have levels, but it makes sense to think of the phases as "sections". So out of the predefined list of sections, the report only has 3 of them. If that makes sense.

Comment: Lol, so basically I have several phases such as "Internal" and "External" and each report will have one or more phases. I want to be able to say report.phases and it returns back which phases the report has. I don't want to have to create a new "Internal" phase for every report. Is that similar to what your example was already somehow? I could just be completely confused. Either way, thanks a lot for your help and feedback!

Comment: That is very good, except the `report_params` method should be **`params.require(:report).permit({phase_ids: []})`**.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you may want is a many to many relationship or a `has_and_belongs_to_many`. To do this you will need to create a join table between Report and Process that will have a `report_id` column and a `phase_id`. For more information check out this documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

In the models you will need to add:

```
Class Report < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :phases

  ...
end
```

and

```
Class Phase < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :reports

  ...
end
```

Comment: So this means I'll have to create duplicate phases because there's going to be 1 phase per report? I can't have 10 phases in the Phases table and each report just belongs to one or more phase?

Comment: No this way you can create 10 phases and then have a many to many mapping between the reports and phases. You won't need to create duplicates of reports of phases

Comment: hmm ok interesting. and lastly, how does the report associate with the phase if there's 20 phases? is there an array or something that gets stored in the phase_id column for the report? thanks for your reference as well. going to go check it out now.

Comment: In the association example, it seems a little different than my case. For example, if an assembly has two parts, then there has to be two assembly entries created with a part_id of the corresponding part. I want to create "one" report and have "many" phases. Not sure if this still applies or not.

Comment: Then it sounds like you want a has_many and belongs_to relationship. Each phase will have an id pointing back to the report and that is how you keep track of them.

Comment: Not sure this applies either as I'd have to create a separate phase for each report. Thanks for your help though. Maybe I'm not clear enough :(

Comment: This pattern wouldn't work - you can't specify each phase